# Excel format in SSIS and warning "The number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe"

Tags: excel, ssis, format

What is difference between value with warning "The number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe" and value without this warning? [Excel source data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgYsI.png)

Problem is when the data are imported in SSIS and rows until 2207 are imported correct but from 2208 are just NULL
[Simple example SSIS diagram and the data from viewer while debuging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6pnt.png)

I use such ConnectionString:

> Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Filename.xlsm;Extended
>   Properties="EXCEL 12.0 MACRO;HDR=NO;IMEX=2";

It doesn't matter if I use

> "IMEX=1" or "IMEX=2"

Columns A..P are (DT_WSTR,255) type.

How to ensure that imported values were the same like in source Excel file (if possible without changing Excel source file)?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a derived column node and convert the columns to text (versus the wstr). Make sure you map the derived column in your output. If text doesn't work try int or numeric.